# launch native iphone application from within another

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I wanted from within my application to open another native iPhone application installed on the device. I used openUrl method and give it the URL schema for that application but it always launch the web application not the native one. Is there a way I can launch the native application instead? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Comment: Which application are you trying to launch?  Do you know that it has a registered URL scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only open applications that have registered in the system.  For example:

Mail:
`[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://aaa@bbb.com"]];`

Phone:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8004664411"]];`

SMS:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:55555"]];`

Tweetie:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tweetie://"]];`

**Note**
This will **ONLY** work if the application has a registered prefix (`tel`, `sms`, `tweetie`, etc...)

Comment: I'm trying to open weather channel application. Does it have a registered prefix ?

Comment: The best thing for you to do is contact the developers of the Application.

Comment: As an additional resource, try looking here to find out who has a url scheme: http://handleopenurl.com/